# Rescale Values in percentage in R

Tags: r

I would need your help to rescale values in percentage in R, expressing the values ​​of the same treatment as a percentage of the maximum value.

For example, I have this input

```
Value Level Treatment
      5     1       A
      7     2       A
      10    4       A
      14    1       B
      20    2       B
      18    4       B
      30    1       C
      30    2       C
      28    4       C
```

I need this output

```
     Value Level Treatment
      50     1       A
      70     2       A
      100    4       A
      70     1       B
      100    2       B
      90     4       B
      100    1       C
      100    2       C
      93.3   4       C
```

I think I can start with

```
    df <- read.table(header = TRUE, text = '
Value Level Treatment
      50     1       A
      70     2       A
      100    4       A
      70     1       B
      100    2       B
      90     4       B
      100    1       C
      100    2       C
      93.3   4       C
')

    tapply(df$Value, df$Treatment, max)
```

But, then, I have no idea how to proceed.

Someone would be so kind to help me?
I hope this could be useful also for other people.

Thanks a lot.

Comment: I'm not sure I follow. Take treatment `A` for example: the maximum value is 4, so why is the percentage for the first row `50` rather than `25` (1/4*100)?

Comment: Because 5 is the 50% of 10 (the maximum value of the treatment A, which is 10 not 4)

Comment: Kindly go through the **one line solution** that I have provided.

Comment: [You should take care of this](http://stackoverflow.com/help/someone-answers)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Thanks for clarifying. In that case it's easy peasy with `dplyr`.

Using the following data:

```
value <- c(5, 7, 10, 14, 20, 18, 30, 30, 28)
level <- c(1, 2, 4)
treatment <- c("A", "A", "A", "B", "B", "B", "C", "C", "C")

df <- data.frame(
  value,
  level,
  treatment,
  stringsAsFactors = FALSE
)
```

Load `tidyverse`/`dplyr`:

```
library("tidyverse")
```

Group by treatment group and calculate based on each in turn with:

```
df <- df %>% 
  group_by(treatment) %>% 
  mutate(value = value / max(value) * 100)

df
## Source: local data frame [9 x 3]
## Groups: treatment [3]
## 
##       value level treatment
##       <dbl> <dbl>     <chr>
## 1  50.00000     1         A
## 2  70.00000     2         A
## 3 100.00000     4         A
## 4  70.00000     1         B
## 5 100.00000     2         B
## 6  90.00000     4         B
## 7 100.00000     1         C
## 8 100.00000     2         C
## 9  93.33333     4         C
```

Which you can format as you see fit.

Answer (score 0):

Refer following two **one line variant**.

You can also use `plyr` package as shown below:

```
ddply(df,~Treatment,summarise,Value=Value/max(Value)*100,Level=Level)
            Treatment     Value    Level
     1         A        50.00000     1
     2         A        70.00000     2
     3         A        100.0000     4
     4         B        70.00000     1
     5         B        100.0000     2
     6         B        90.00000     4
     7         C        100.0000     1
     8         C        100.0000     2
     9         C        93.33333     4
```

Following is the other variant using `data.table` package:

```
> dt <- data.table(df)
> dt[,list(Value=Value/max(Value)*100,Level=Level),by=Treatment]
            Treatment     Value    Level
     1         A        50.00000     1
     2         A        70.00000     2
     3         A        100.0000     4
     4         B        70.00000     1
     5         B        100.0000     2
     6         B        90.00000     4
     7         C        100.0000     1
     8         C        100.0000     2
     9         C        93.33333     4
```

Answer (score 0):

We can use `ave` from `base R`

```
df1$Value <- with(df1, round(100*Value/ave(Value, Treatment, FUN = max)))
df1$Value
#[1]  50  70 100  70 100  90 100 100  93
```